# How to find the first character in a C++ string

Tags: c++, string

I have a string which starts out with a lot of spaces.  If I want to find out the position of the first character that is not a space, how would I do that?

Comment: What encoding is your string? If it's ASCII, then there are only 4 whitespace characters, and Vlad's solution with find_first_not_of is good. ASCII or Latin 1 strings probably cover teaching exercises. If your string is UTF-8 or a wide character std::wstring (as it might be in a real application) then ask another question.

Comment: Yes, in those cases one would be able to use the `find_if` solution at the botom of that same post (optionally using BLL's `boost::labda::bind(isspace, _1, my_locale)` to tie a specific locale `my_locale` to `isspace` instead of using the default).

Answer (score 17):

See [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of).

To find the **position (index)** of the first non-space character:

```
str.find_first_not_of(' ');
```

To find the position (index) of the first non-blank character:

```
str.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n");
```

It returns `str.npos` if `str` is empty or consists entirely of blanks.

You can use `find_first_not_of` to trim the offending leading blanks:

```
str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n"));
```

---

If you do not want to hardcode which characters count as blanks (e.g. **use a locale**) you can still make use of `isspace` and `find_if` in more or less the manner originally suggested by *sbi*, but taking care to negate `isspace`, e.g.:

```
string::iterator it_first_nonspace = find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), not1(isspace));
// e.g. number of blank characters to skip
size_t chars_to_skip = it_first_nonspace - str.begin();
// e.g. trim leading blanks
str.erase(str.begin(), it_first_nonspace);
```

Answer (score 6):

I have only one question: do you actually need the extra blanks ?

I would invoke the power of [Boost.String](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) there ;)

```
std::string str1 = "     hello world!     ";
std::string str2 = boost::trim_left_copy(str1);   // str2 == "hello world!     "
```

There are many operations (`find`, `trim`, `replace`, ...) as well as predicates available in this library, whenever you need `string` operations that are not provided out of the box, check here. Also the algorithms have several variants each time (case-insensitive and copy in general).