# not1 was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I was following some information from this: [How to find the first character in a C++ string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346737/how-to-find-the-first-character-in-a-c-string)

When I tried to implement it into my code, I got the error not1 was not declared in this scope.

```
void ASTree::indent(int ind, int inc) {
    std::string theText;

    for (std::vector<ASTree*>::const_iterator i = child.begin(); i != child.end(); ++i) {
        switch ((*i)->nodeType) {
            case category:
                (*i)->indent(ind + inc, inc);
                break;
            case token:
                {
                //out << std::setw(indent) << " ";
                theText = (*i)->text; // << std::endl;
                std::string::iterator firstChar = std::find_if(theText.begin(), theText.end(), std::not1(std::isspace));
                theText.erase(theText.begin(), firstChar);
                (*i)->text = theText;
                }
                break;
            case whitespace:
                //out << (*i)->text;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm somewhat new to C++ and working on these projects for in class.

Comment: Well, not1 isn't declared anywhere in this code. Are you sure you haven't missed something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you included [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/not1/) header:

```
#include <functional>
```

Also, use `std::not1`, not just `not1`, for it is defined in `std` namespace.

I hope you've not written `using namespace std` in your code, which is a bad idea anyway.

---

Alright after reading this comment by you:

```
get yet another error. :) no matching function for call to ânot1(<unresolved overloaded function type>)â I also updated the code above to show you my current
```

I guess there is another function with name `isspace` is present in `std` namespace, which is causing the problem while resolving the names.

So here are two solutions. Try one by one:

- Use just `::isspace`. Without using `std`. Just `::isspace`. See if it works!
- Or, cast explicitly to help the compiler in selecting the desired overload, as

  ```
   std::not1(((int)(*)(int))(std::isspace));
  ```

Since the casting looks very clumsy, you can use typedef also, as:

```
 //define this inside the function, or outside the function!
 typedef int (*fun)(int);

 //then do this:
 std::not1((fun)(std::isspace))
```

I hope this should help you.

---

A similar problem has been seen before, see this:

- ["Unresolved overloaded function type" while trying to use for_each with iterators and function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531866/unresolved-overloaded-function-type-c)

Comment: @Tom: In that case, just prefixing `not1` with `std::` would work fine!

Comment: I had tried using std::not1 a couple of times, but I get a huge error with a bunch at the bottom that say: error: no match for call to â(std::unary_negate<int(int)>) (char&)â

Comment: @Tom: I saw you're not prefixing `isspace` with `std::`. Please use `std::isspace`. Also, `#include <cctype>`. If it still gives error, then post the whole error message.

Comment: I've tried adding std:: before and I did again and included the cctype and get yet another error. :) no matching function for call to ânot1(<unresolved overloaded function type>)â I also updated the code above to show you my current.

Comment: @Tom: Now that makes sense. Just use `::isspace`. I guess there is another function template defined in `std` namespace.

Comment: Still getting that huge error with ::isspace. Error pasted to http://pastebin.com/GfLFyf0a

Comment: I am still having issues, but I have to go to work, so I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks for all the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

To use `std::not1` you need to `#include <functional>`, also you need to prefix it with the namespace properly (if you don't have a `using` directive):

```
std::string::iterator firstChar = std::find_if(
    theText.begin(),
    theText.end(),
    std::not1(isspace));
```